# Object required when retrieving value from InputBox

Tags: vba, object

Hey guys I have a a coding issue in vba.

```
 Dim table As String
 Set table = InputBox("Text","Title","Default")
```

I then get the message:

Error while compiling
Object required

The phrase

```
    table =
```

Is marked blue

Why do I get the error while compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) statement is used with variables that are an `Object` type.

Per the VBE Glossary for [object-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement);

> A type of object exposed by an application through Automation, for example, Application, File, Range, and Sheet. Use the Object Browser or refer to the application's documentation for a complete listing of available objects.

A `String` is not an object data type so you don't need to include the `Set` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

If `InputBox` does return a `String` you have to remove the `Set` (which is only needed for objects):

```
Dim table As String
table = InputBox("Text","Title","Default")
```